# O que são rastro de pilha e estouro de pilha?

Tags: stack

A única coisa que sei é que refere-se ao uso da memória mas defina **pilha** e porque acontece com tanta frequência ?

Comment: Relacionada: [O que são e onde estão o “stack” e “heap”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3797/o-que-são-e-onde-estão-o-stack-e-heap?rq=1)

Comment: Sobre nomenclatura: rasto de pilha == stacktrace (fonte http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~rimsa/documents/decom009/lessons/Aula08.pdf )